# How to resolve end of file error in php code?

Tags: php

I am new to php. I have a sign up page that takes in few user details and makes an account. On running the code I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 347
```

I have seen few other posts related to the same issue but I didnt find any of those helpful for my code. I have reviewed the code many times to see what I have done wrong but couldn't find my mistake. Please help with the statement or point where I have gone wrong. Thanks in advance.

My code is below:

**sign-up.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Trip Planner | Sign Up </title>
<!-- for-mobile-apps -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Xtreme Travel Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Android Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
        function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- //for-mobile-apps -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/styles.css?v=1.6" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- js -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js?v=1.7"></script>
<!-- //js -->
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidation()
{
var uid = document.registration.userid;
var passid = document.registration.passid;
var uemail = document.registration.email;
if(userid_validation(uid,5,12))
{

if(passid_validation(passid,7,12))
{

if(ValidateEmail(uemail))
{
}
}
}
return false;
}


function userid_validation(uid,mx,my)
{
var uid_len = uid.value.length;
if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx)
{
alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);
uid.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}

function passid_validation(passid,mx,my)
{
var passid_len = passid.value.length;
if (passid_len == 0 ||passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx)
{
alert("Password should not be empty / length be between "+mx+" to "+my);
passid.focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}


function ValidateEmail(uemail)
{
var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
if(uemail.value.match(mailformat))
{
//alert("You have entered a valid email address!");
return true;
}
else
{
alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
uemail.focus();
return false;
}
}


</script>
<!-- start-smoth-scrolling -->
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->open('mytrip.db');
        }
    }
    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db){
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    } else {

    }
    $id=null;
    $pass=null;
    $email=null;
    $fname=null;
    $lname=null;
    $id_exists=false;

    if (isset($_POST['uid'])) {
        $id = $_POST['uid'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['passid'])) {
        $pass = $_POST['passid'];
    }

      if (isset($_POST['uemail'])) {
        $email = $_POST['uemail'];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['first'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['first'];
    }

      if (isset($_POST['last'])) {
        $lname = $_POST['last'];



    $result= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE ID = '".$id. "';" ;
    $count= $db->querySingle($result);

    if ($count > 0)
    {
        $id_exists = true;
        echo "This id is not available. Please enter a valid id. ";
    }

    else
    {
        $sql= " INSERT INTO Users (ID, PASSWORD, EMAIL, FNAME, LNAME)
          VALUES ('$id','$pass','$email', '$fname', '$lname'); " ;
        $ret = $db->query($sql);
        $_SESSION['Id'] = $id;
        header("location:index.php");
    }


    $db->close();
}
?>  
<body>
<!-- banner -->
    <div class="banner1">
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav class="pull">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="active"> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php"> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php" class="menu">Popular Places<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
                            <ul class="nav-sub">
                                <li><a href="index.php">Place 1</a></li>                                             
                                <li><a href="index.php">Place 2</a></li>                                                                                                
                                <li><a href="index.php">Place 3</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                            <script>
                                $( "li a.menu" ).click(function() {
                                $( "ul.nav-sub" ).slideToggle( 300, function() {
                                // Animation complete.
                                });
                                });
                            </script>
                        <li><a href="index.php"> Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.php"> Mail us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="head-logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><span>M</span>y Trip Planner<i>Feeling Amazing Tour</i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <div class="hero fa-navicon fa-2x nav_slide_button" id="hero">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/menu.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- banner -->
<!-- sign-in -->
    <div class="sign-in">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="in-form">
                <h3>Register Here</h3>
                <p class="use">Having hands on experience in creating innovative 
                                designs,I do offer design solutions which harness.</p>
                <div class="sign-in-form">
                    <div class="in-form Personal">
                        <h4>Personal Information</h4>
                        <form method="post" name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation();">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname*" required=" " name="first">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Lastname*" required=" " name="last">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Emailaddress*" required=" " name="uemail">

                        <h4 class="kij">Login Information</h4>

                            <input type="text" placeholder="Id*" required=" "  name="uid">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" required=" " name="passid">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password*" required=" ">
                            <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- //sign-in -->
<!-- footer-top -->
    <div class="footer-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3 footer-top-grid">
                <h3>About <span> My Trip Planner</span></h3>
                <p>Lets you plan the finest trips.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 footer-top-grid">
                <h3>THE <span>TAGS</span></h3>
                <div class="unorder">
                    <ul class="tag2">
                        <li><a href="#">pool</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">gym</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">beach</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="tag2">
                        <li><a href="#">asian</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">thai</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">chinese</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">american</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="tag2">
                        <li><a href="#">theme park</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">wildlife</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">heritage</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="tag2">
                        <li><a href="#">shopping malls</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">local shops</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">boutiques</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 footer-top-grid">
                <h3> User <span> Reviews</span></h3>
                <ul class="twi">
                    <li>Location is close to empire state building and near bus stop. Staff was pleasant on check in. 
                     <span></span></li>
                    <li>Outstanding food and service. Would return without hesitation.
                    <span></span></li>
                    <li>My wife and I love walking around and exploring cities. and New York is one of the few cities in USA you can enjoy doing that. SoHo has a great vibe about it, and we enjoyed walking around, grabbing a quick bite, and doing some shopping.
                    <span></span></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 footer-top-grid">
                <h3> Popular <span> Destinations</span></h3>
                <div class="flickr-grids">
                    <div class="flickr-grid">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/minar.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flickr-grid">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/bad.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flickr-grid">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/kua1.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>

                    <div class="flickr-grid">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/kua.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flickr-grid">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/newyork.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flickr-grid">
                        <a href="#"><img src="images/can1.jpg" alt=" " class="img-responsive" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- //footer-top -->
<!-- footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="footer-left">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php"><i>M</i>y Trip Planner</a><span> |</span></li>
                    <!-- <li><p>The awesome agency. <span>0800 (123) 4567 // Australia 746 PO</span></p></li> -->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-right">
                <p>© 2017 My Trip Planner. All rights reserved | </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- //footer -->
<!-- here stars scrolling icon -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
                var defaults = {
                containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
                containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
                scrollSpeed: 1200,
                easingType: 'linear' 
                };
            */

            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

            });
    </script>
<!-- //here ends scrolling icon -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check your closings, you might be lacking one

Comment: My recommendation is use a php editor like PHPStorm or NetBeans to avoid this type of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this error because you miss "}" at line 141:

```
if (isset($_POST['last'])) {
    $lname = $_POST['last'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing bracket to line 141, so that the code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['last'])) {
  $lname = $_POST['last'];
}
```

I tested your code locally and this is what fixed the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

What IDE or text editor do you use to write your code? I would suggest you something what points out such simple mistakes. For example netbeans for php or php storm, netbeans is free, php storm is not. Both of these editors will show to you your mistakes like this.